# I want to calculate total elapsed time for logs in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have all the lines in `textLines1` and I want to calculate the average elapsed time for all these lines. I have tried regular expressions for this. But it is giving me wrong calculation.

Log file format:

```
INFO:  WX ADVSearch = Server:testserver Entity:BUG User:acucu Elapsed Time:274ms 
INFO:  WX ADVSearch = Server:testserver Entity:BUG User:acucu Elapsed Time:274ms
```

Code I have tried is :

```
List<string> textLines1 = new List<string>(users);
string x = string.Join(",", textLines1);
Regex regex = new Regex(@"Elapsed Time:\s*(?<value>\d+\.?\d*)\s*ms");
Match match = regex.Match(x);
double totalTime = 0;
int count = 0;

foreach (string line in textLines1)
{
    if (match.Captures.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            count++;
            double time = Double.Parse(match.Groups["value"].Value);
            totalTime += time;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // no number
        }
    }
}

double average = totalTime / count;
Console.WriteLine("ADVAverage=" + average);
```

Comment: How about textLines1.IndexOf(..)

Comment: Are you getting correct elapsed time values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had a few errors (in my opinion):

1. `string.Join` receives a `string[]`, and you were passing a `List<string>`.
2. You don't really need to do any `string.Join`. Instead, just iterate through each line, and capture the match in each line.

See the code below:

```
//I don't think you have to do this. Instead, you can iterate through `users`
string[] textLines1 = new List<string>(users).ToArray();
double totalTime = 0;
int count = 0;

//For each line
foreach (string line in textLines1) {
    //Here we match against this line
    var m = Regex.Match(line, @"Elapsed Time:\s*(?<value>\d+\.?\d*)\s*ms");
    //If it matched...
    if (m.Success) {
        try
        {
            count++;
            double time = Double.Parse(m.Groups["value"].Value);
            totalTime += time;
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            // no number
        }
    }
}

double average = totalTime / count;
Console.WriteLine("ADVAverage=" + average);
```

Below is the output:

> ADVAverage=274

Comment: **downvoter:** Could you leave a comment? Anything you would like to share? Did you test my code?

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void CalculateTotalTime()
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"INFO:.+Elapsed Time:(?<milliseconds>\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)ms");

    double totalMilliseconds = (from Match match in pattern.Matches(input)
                                let milliseconds = double.Parse(match.Groups["milliseconds"].Value)
                                select milliseconds).Sum();

    TimeSpan elapsed = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(totalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D3}", elapsed.Hours, elapsed.Minutes, elapsed.Seconds, elapsed.Milliseconds);
}


private const string input =
    "INFO: WX ADVSearch = Server:yukon.corp.adobe.com Entity:BUG User:acucu Elapsed Time:274ms\n" +
    "INFO: WX ADVSearch = Server:yukon.corp.adobe.com Entity:BUG User:acucu Elapsed Time:27.5ms\n" +
    "INFO: WX ADVSearch = Server:yukon.corp.adobe.com Entity:BUG User:acucu Elapsed Time:500.55ms";
```

I just wrote and tested the method above with the given test data and the calculations are accurate.

Answer (score -1):

I think your Regex is not correct enough. You might want to consider matching it too the following:

```
"Elapsed Time:.*ms"
```

To get the number, you could truncate the first 13 characters and the last 2 characters.
Then per line, you could use `Double.TryParse` (as you are not doing any special handling yourself, you can let the `TryParse` method do that for you and keep your own code cleaner) to get the number you are interested in.

You can check you regex to see if it's properly matching on websites, like http://regexpal.com/.

Comment: I'm pretty sure his regex is correct. Also, why would he truncate after matching, when he can already parse the numeric values directly from the regular expression? (as he is doing now...)